# I cannot build the application in VS code, when i am trying to connect the app with firebase. Following is the error i get when i start running it

Tags: firebase, flutter, build

I have followed the steps for adding dependency accordingly.
ProcessException: Process "F:\firebase_demo\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'F:\firebase_demo\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
--scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
  Command: F:\firebase_demo\android\gradlew.bat app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.



#-------------------------Here is the change i brought to build gradle


dependencies {  
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"  
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'  
}  

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: lemme see your build.gradle

Comment: added to the post

Comment: flutter requires your project to be androidX enabled.migrate your project to androidX and it will clear your errors https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate  https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very similar problem with "ASCII". Turns out I had put my google firebase files in the wrong folder. Double check the position?
In Android Studio it is: android/app/google-services.json